# React Native - Getting Style from a Function (Android)

Tags: javascript, mobile, reactjs, react-native

What I'm trying to achieve is, add views dynamically depending on what comes up from JSON. For example, one event can be presented with red, another can be presented with blue. The app should insert a view according to this.

```
class MainPage2 extends Component {


 constructor () {  
super()
var sleepTime = ["15/07/2016 15:00:00", "15/07/2016 14:20:30"];
var minuteDifference = Math.round((((sleepTime[0] - sleepTime[1]) / 1000)/60));

var width = {timeAsleep: 120, timeAwake:60, timeAway:60}
this.state = {
  timeAsleep: width.timeAsleep, 
  timeAwake: width.timeAwake,
  timeAway:  width.timeAway, 
  array: [1,2]
}  //set the changeable values, we will get it from Json in our app
  } styler (num) {


    if (num == 1)
    return styles.AsleepStyle;

    if (num==2)
    return styles.AwakeStyle;

    if (num==3)
    return styles.AwayStyle;

    return styles.AwayStyle;
  }

  render () {
   const {timeAsleep, timeAwake, timeAway} = this.state
  let Arr = this.state.array.map((a, i) => {
 return <View key={i} style={this.styler(a)}></View> });

   return (
   <ScrollView>

    <Text>First</Text>
    <View style={this.styler}/>
    { Arr }

    <Text>Second</Text>
    <TouchableHighlight onPress={ () => this._onPressOut() }>
      <Text>Push</Text>
    </TouchableHighlight>

  <View style={styles.viewLayout}>


    <View style={[styles.bar, styles.AsleepStyle, {width: timeAsleep}]}/> 
    <View style={[styles.bar, styles.AwakeStyle, {width: timeAwake}]}/>
    <View style={[styles.bar, styles.AwayStyle, {width: timeAway}]}/>
  </View>
   </ScrollView>  

   )  }}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
viewLayout: {
   flex: 1, flexDirection: 'row',padding:20
},

 bar: {


height: 18

},

AsleepStyle: {
backgroundColor: '#F55443'
},
AwakeStyle: {
backgroundColor: '#FCBD24'
},
   AwayStyle: {
backgroundColor: '#59838B'
}
});

module.exports = MainPage2;
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: It's not really clear from your question how your code is structured. Some more context would be helpful. Where is this function defined, for example?

Comment: I edited the question. And added all the code

Comment: Thanks for wanting to mark this as solved. To do so, please add an answer below, and click the adjacent tick mark.

Answer (score 0):

If styler is in the same class then use **this.styler**:

```
 render () {
     const {timeAsleep, timeAwake, timeAway} = this.state
     let Arr = this.state.array.map((a, i) => {
     return <View key={i} style={this.styler(a)}></View> });
 }
```

Comment: Thanks, now it sees the function, however, it is still not working.

Comment: Can you elaborate? what is not working? anything in log?

Comment: There is a warning.
Failed prop type: Invalid prop 'style' of type 'function' supplied to 'View', expected 'object'. in View

Comment: <View style={this.styler}/>. this is the problem. It a function, not a style object

Comment: Thanks for all help, I solved it, I made a small mistake with syntax